# Meaning of K in Algebraic K theory

Tags: algebraic-k-theory

I am reading algebraic K-theory but I have doubt not in the subject but in the name. I want to ask what K stands in the word Algebraic K-theory as well as in Topological K-theory.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this page](https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/about-us/life-oxford-mathematics/oxford-mathematics-alphabet/k-k-theory) from the University of Oxford, the K stands for Klasse.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this page